# Cleaning up a 5V Switching DC-DC converter for low noise 5V output

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply

I have a project that I have to hook to a 5V bus coming from [this DC-DC switching converter](http://www.lineagepower.com/oem/pdf/SW003A0A.pdf).

I need to clean this up to use with a logamp ([LOG114](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbos301a/sbos301a.pdf)), photodiode, and ADC ([ADS8519](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads8519.pdf)). I would also like this circuit to work on future projects with similar power supplies.

Comment: How clean is clean?  More precisely, what is the ripple voltage you'll tolerate across the frequency spectrum in millivolts?  The marketing blurb for that part specifies "Low output ripple and noise", but the electrical specifications say that it produces <25mV RMS of ripple between 5 Hz and 20 MHz, which is already pretty low.

Answer (score 13):

You cannot avoid ripple on the output of a switching regulator.  You can somewhat minimize it, and you can shift it to a different frequency, but you cannot eliminate it.

A linear regulator has no ripple on the output.  There is noise on the output, but not ripple in the same sense as a switching regulator.   Of course, linear regulators have their own issues like terrible efficiency.

When I need something like relatively high efficiency *AND* super low noise I will use both a switching regulator and a low-noise, low-dropout linear regulator.  For a +5v output I will set up the switcher for a +6v output, and then use the linear regulator to bring that down to a clean 5v.

Note:  not all LDO linear regulators are created equal.  Some have lower noise than others and some have lower voltage drops.  Pick wisely.  Sorry, I don't have part numbers handy.

Some people would use additional filtering on the output of the switcher instead of a linear regulator, but I find that such a filter isn't worth it.  Those filters are based on an LC topology and require large inductors and caps to be effective.  A linear regulator can be smaller and cheaper than a filter (but somewhat less power efficient).

Comment: +1. You may be able to find ripple rejection/PSRR figures in dB in linear regulator datasheets for frequencies other than 120Hz. This switcher operates around 300kHz-450kHz.

Comment: That's a great approach, but I think it's important to note that this approach won't work very well for this particular module, which has a hard-coded +5V output.  You might be able to use an LDO to bring this down to 3.3V, but it won't be helpful if you need a +5V supply.

Comment: @KevinVermeer In the question, the OP didn't say which regulator he's using.  It could be one of the adjustable ones in that same datasheet.  Even so, look at the trim pin on page 14 of the datasheet.  It explains how to tweak the output voltage.  This tweak even works on the "fixed" output versions of the modules.

Comment: @DavidKessner - Ah, didn't read closely enough.  Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: David, just a small thing I don't understand: how do you choose to output 6V from the switching regulator, instead of -say- 5.2V? Is 1V the minimum dropout of the LDO? Or it helps suppressing better the noise?

Comment: @clabacchio You never want the voltage to drop below 5V+LDO_DropOut_Voltage.  So any noise or ripple on the switching output cannot let that rail drop lower than that.  And I would add a little bit more so that there is some margin left.  My 6v figure was a "good start", but it could be improved on once all the parts are picked out.